# How to use the odata expand-parameter in a SAPUI5 Table?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, expand, mockserver

I want to show data from 2 odata entities that have a one to many relationship inside a SAPUI5 table.

I have tried multiple ways of referencing in the table (e.g entries/title). Debugging showed that the data from entries is received but not displayed in the table.

```
<Table
    items="{
        path: '/Line',
        parameters : {
        expand : 'entries'
        }
    }" >
    <columns>
        <Column />
        <Column />
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
        <Label text="{ID}" />
        <Label text="{title} 
            {shape}" />
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

This is my metadata.xml

```xml
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" xmlns:ux="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/OData4SAP/UX" xmlns:gp="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/GenericPlayer" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="TimelineService">
            <EntityType Name="Entry">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="title" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="startDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
                <Property Name="shape" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="lineID_ID" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="lineID" Relationship="TimelineService.Entry_lineID" FromRole="Entry" ToRole="Line"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Line">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="entries" Relationship="TimelineService.Entry_lineID" FromRole="Line" ToRole="Entry"/>
            </EntityType>
            <Association Name="Entry_lineID">
                <End Type="TimelineService.Entry" Multiplicity="*" Role="Entry"/>
                <End Type="TimelineService.Line" Multiplicity="0..1" Role="Line"/>
                <ReferentialConstraint>
                    <Principal Role="Line">
                        <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                    </Principal>
                    <Dependent Role="Entry">
                        <PropertyRef Name="lineID_ID"/>
                    </Dependent>
                </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <EntityContainer Name="EntityContainer" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Entry" EntityType="TimelineService.Entry"/>
                <EntitySet Name="Line" EntityType="TimelineService.Line"/>
                <AssociationSet Name="Entry_lineID" Association="TimelineService.Entry_lineID">
                    <End EntitySet="Entry" Role="Entry"/>
                    <End EntitySet="Line" Role="Line"/>
                </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution below:

Open your **Controller**, and execute a bind element to your context controller.

```
this.getView().bindElement({
    path : "/Line",
    parameters : {
        "expand" : "entries"
    }
});
```

Now, modify your **View**

```
<Table items="{
    path: 'entries'
}">
<columns>
    <Column />
    <Column />
</columns>
<items>
    <ColumnListItem>
    <Label text="{ID}" />
    <Label text="{title} 
        {shape}" />
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

Thank you.